# Is it possible to add javascript functions to an embedded webmap?

Tags: javascript, html, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have creatd a webmap on ArcGis online.
The embedded map is in an `iframe`.

I am using `HTML` and `Javascript` to develop something whith `Phonegap`.

Does ArcGis have a JS API similar to GoogleMap?

Answer (score 2):

yes it's perfectly possible and fully documented in their api

you can find the [full docs here](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jshelp/)

There is also this [repo on github](https://github.com/Esri/quickstart-map-phonegap) with a phonegap/arcgis starter set up

Comment: alright will take a look! thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.
Use the ArcGis API https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/ instead of the GoogleMaps API.

If your project targets `Phonegap`, it is even more easy: https://github.com/Esri/quickstart-map-phonegap

> A set of simple samples that show how to get started with the ArcGIS API for JavaScript and PhoneGap/Cordova. These samples provide best practices for using PhoneGap and Cordova across different device operating systems and within the PhoneGap/Cordova application lifecycle.